# ChartJS chart not scaling after adding values

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a dynamically updating chart created using ChartJS. But as I add more values the chart is not updating/ rescaling x axis to show these values. I see only two values and the line goes out of the chart when I add more. The Y axis is auto scaling based on the values I add.

```
<div id="event-area" class="row">
        <canvas id="valueChart"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
var chartConfig = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [],
            options: {
                responsive: true
            }
        }
    };
    window.onload = function () {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('valueChart').getContext('2d');
        window.valueChart= new Chart(ctx, chartConfig);
    };
</script>

//This is the code I use to update the chart
if (request.data["1005"] != undefined){
    var datasetIndex = chartMap.get(request.dataSetName)
    chartConfig.data.datasets[datasetIndex].data.push(request.data["value"]);
    window.valueChart.update({duration: 0});
}
```

Simiar issue in Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/3c7bzmk8/2 (If you keep pressing to add values the chart x axis does not scale)

Comment: Please create a snippet and reproduce your problem there.

Comment: Added a JSFiddle sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may change the `"data: { labels: [],}"` array as well.

Push values into the labels array after push data to datasets.data, and the chart will be changed.

```
options.data.labels.push('another color')
```

Or rebuild the whole labels and datasets arrays and the chart will be rescaling.

You can change the existing values in there and it will be rerendered.